# Undefined class variable when defined in constructor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Just started using CoffeeScript and have hit a wall. In my code below I construct WebSocketServer with a number as the first argument and a function as the second argument. When the code is ran and the websocket receives a message, `@msgHandler` is now magically undefined. I tried to work around this by setting a variable `handler` to `@msgHandler` but that ended up being undefined as well. If anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear them, thanks!

main.coffee

```
#Used to communicate with browser interface
webSocketServ = new sio.WebSocketServer Sauce.Server.WebSocketPort, (data, socketId) ->
    try
        json = JSON.parse(data)
        msgType  = json.msgType
    catch error
        return

    if (this.isAuthed(socketId))
        switch msgType
            when "auth"

            else
                io.websocket 'TODO: ' + cmd        
    else
        if msgType is 'auth'
            token = json.token
```

socket.coffee

```
class WebSocketServer
    constructor: (@port, @msgHandler) ->
        @webSockets = []
        @handlers = {}
        @test = []
        @authedSockes = []
        @listen(@port);
        console.log @msgHandler #msgHandler is defined here as [ Function ]

    listen: (port) ->
        @wsServ = engine.listen port
        @wsServ.on 'connection', @onConnect
        io.socket "WebServer socket started on port #{port}"

    onConnect: (client) ->
        io.websocket 'New connection with id of ' + client.id

        handler = @msgHandler #@msgHandler is undefined here?

        client.on 'message', (data) ->
            handler data, client.id
            io.websocket '[' + this.id + '] ' + JSON.stringify(data)

        client.on 'close', ->
            io.websocket '[' + this.id + '] Disconnect'

        client.on 'error', (err) ->
            io.websocket "IO error: " + err
```

compiled socket.coffee

```
  WebSocketServer = (function() {
    function WebSocketServer(port, msgHandler) {
      this.port = port;
      this.msgHandler = msgHandler;
      this.webSockets = [];
      this.handlers = {};
      this.test = [];
      this.authedSockes = [];
      this.listen(this.port);
      console.log(this.msgHandler);
    }

    WebSocketServer.prototype.listen = function(port) {
      this.wsServ = engine.listen(port);
      this.wsServ.on('connection', this.onConnect);
      return io.socket("WebServer socket started on port " + port);
    };

    WebSocketServer.prototype.onConnect = function(client) {
      var handler;
      io.websocket('New connection with id of ' + client.id);
      handler = this.msgHandler;
      client.on('message', function(data) {
        handler(data, client.id);
        return io.websocket('[' + this.id + '] ' + JSON.stringify(data));
      });
      client.on('close', function() {
        return io.websocket('[' + this.id + '] Disconnect');
      });
      return client.on('error', function(err) {
        return io.websocket("IO error: " + err);
      });
    };

    WebSocketServer.prototype.isAuthed = function(socketId) {
      return __indexOf.call(this.authedSockets, user) >= 0;
    };

    WebSocketServer.prototype.authSocket = function(socketId) {
      this.authedSockets.push(socketId);
      return io.websocket('Authed socket with ID of ' + socketId);
    };

    WebSocketServer.prototype.deauthSocket = function(socketId) {
      return this.authedSockets = this.authedSockets.filter(function(word) {
        return word !== socketId;
      });
    };

    return WebSocketServer;

  })();
```

Comment: Haha, I'm limited to it at the moment - abandoned open source project I'm modifying uses it... @LeonardoVotocelli

Comment: funnier that it's an "abandoned project" - good luck fellow traveler

Comment: if you log `this` inside of `onConnect` is it actually referring to an instance of the class?

Comment: I don't see an issue here. what's the problem you're having? Did you console log out @msgHandler? And it's not getting set?

Comment: @Allen Yeah, underneath the line I commented in socket.coffee I tried that. It returned as undefined.

Comment: @Mathletics It's returning an instance of `@wsServ` for some reason...I've added the compiled JS code to the OP

Comment: line 2 in your `listen` method: `onConnect` is an event handler called with a different context. You need to make `msgHandler` available in that context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an undefined class variable, you mean that you cannot access an *instance property*. It's caused by the common [`this` context issue in callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) - you cannot just pass a method and expect it to know the instance.

Fortunately, this can be trivially fixed in CS using the [fat arrow syntax](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) for the method definition and other callbacks:

```
    onConnect: (client) =>
#                       ^^
        io.websocket 'New connection with id of ' + client.id

        handler = @msgHandler # @ is now the expected instance

        client.on 'message', (data) =>
#                                   ^^
            handler data, client.id
            io.websocket '[' + @id + '] ' + JSON.stringify(data)
#                              ^ or did you mean to use `client.` here?

        client.on 'close', =>
#                          ^^
            io.websocket '[' + @id + '] Disconnect'

        client.on 'error', (err) ->
            io.websocket "IO error: " + err
```

---

A different (and possibly better) approach might be to let your `WebSocketServer` class *inherit* from the engine's class, instead of building a wrapper around it. Since all callbacks are called on the server instance usually, you could access your properties directly without needing to bind the callbacks.